# What the function type in Reac-Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a function as below:

```
  const myFunction = () => () => {
       //do something
    }
```

Does anyone help me explain what's means the function as above.

Comment: What part are you specifically struggling with?

Comment: I don't know why have "() => () =>",this is my first time encountering a func like this.

Comment: This is called currying and used to be able to create a function by calling `myFunction()`. A typical use-case in React is creating a state setter function for an input's onChange while passing the name of the state key. https://jsfiddle.net/2g0s3wc6/

Answer (score 0):

It's a function that returns a function. An example of where you might use this would be to reduce repetition when you need a set of similar callback functions. Here's an example from a recent React Native app that I've worked on: Consider a pocket calculator app that has a grid of similar buttons, each with an onPress callback that needs a distinct value to be used in the callback function:

```
// Snippet from React component
...
const onPress = value => () => {
  console.log('You pressed ' + value);
}

return (
  <>
    <Button title="ONE" onPress={onPress(1)} />
    <Button title="TWO" onPress={onPress(2)} />
    <Button title="THREE" onPress={onPress(3)} />
  </>
)
```

Each button gets an onPress callback function with a ()=>{} signature, as required, that does something with a distinct value. Rather than having to declare three functions, we've just declared one. Nice and tidy.